# Can't switch to the second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, buttonclick

I cant switch activities in my Android app. I tried everything, but it still gives error:

> "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Main:

```
public void toMoney(View view) {

    Intent toMoneyOut = new Intent(this, moneyOut.class);
    startActivity(toMoneyOut);
    //toMoney is onClick method

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adget.adget">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/adgeticon21"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/adget_icon_round"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".TheScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".moneyOut">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TheScreen" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALUT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
11-27 09:59:18.838 4990-4990/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-27 09:59:19.647 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-27 09:59:19.920 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-27 09:59:19.928 4990-5003/com.adget.adget W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.941ms
11-27 09:59:20.291 4990-5003/com.adget.adget W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.193ms
11-27 09:59:20.295 4990-5003/com.adget.adget I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1606(361KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 1539KB/1989KB, paused 6.325ms total 17.232ms
11-27 09:59:20.334 4990-5003/com.adget.adget W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.113ms
11-27 09:59:20.417 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
11-27 09:59:20.417 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
11-27 09:59:20.497 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
11-27 09:59:20.497 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
11-27 09:59:20.547 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@00000006@DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
11-27 09:59:20.548 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
11-27 09:59:20.548 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
11-27 09:59:20.638 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.ChimeraRewardedVideoAdCreatorImpl
11-27 09:59:20.801 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-27 09:59:20.802 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
11-27 09:59:20.910 4990-5003/com.adget.adget W/art: Suspending all threads took: 35.320ms
11-27 09:59:20.918 4990-5003/com.adget.adget I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7061(702KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(308KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 5MB/6MB, paused 36.744ms total 128.577ms
11-27 09:59:20.933 4990-5068/com.adget.adget W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
                                                    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.adget.adget-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:167)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:152)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.g(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:43)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.c.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:47)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:4)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.af.call(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:3)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ag.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11509280:3)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement
                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                ... 13 more
                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
11-27 09:59:20.933 4990-5068/com.adget.adget W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firbase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
11-27 09:59:20.940 4990-5003/com.adget.adget I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 400(85KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(355KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 5MB/6MB, paused 5.690ms total 12.860ms
11-27 09:59:20.987 4990-5070/com.adget.adget D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true

                                                               [ 11-27 09:59:21.015  4990: 4990 D/         ]
                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fbdcf86a5c0, tid 4990


                                                               [ 11-27 09:59:21.153  4990: 4990 W/         ]
                                                               Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
11-27 09:59:21.156 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/Atlas: Validating map...
11-27 09:59:21.306 4990-5064/com.adget.adget I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 37 (4309839-x86_64) (code 100008)

                                                               [ 11-27 09:59:21.348  4990: 5070 D/         ]
                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fbdbb238510, tid 5070


                                                               [ 11-27 09:59:21.349  4990: 5070 W/         ]
                                                               Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
11-27 09:59:21.351 4990-5070/com.adget.adget I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-27 09:59:21.352 4990-5070/com.adget.adget W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
11-27 09:59:21.394 4990-5070/com.adget.adget D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fbdcedc9200: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-27 09:59:21.441 4990-5064/com.adget.adget I/LibraryLoader: Loading: webviewchromium
11-27 09:59:21.463 4990-5064/com.adget.adget I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 22 ms (timestamps 6857-6879)
11-27 09:59:21.463 4990-5064/com.adget.adget I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
11-27 09:59:21.482 4990-5064/com.adget.adget W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
11-27 09:59:21.542 4990-5070/com.adget.adget D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fbdcedc9200: ver 2 0
11-27 09:59:21.547 4990-5070/com.adget.adget D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-27 09:59:21.597 4990-5070/com.adget.adget D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fbdcedc9200: ver 2 0
11-27 09:59:21.703 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
11-27 09:59:21.714 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 09:59:22.033 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/Ads: Server parameters: {"campaign_id":"739275108","gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544\/5224354917\/cak=no_cache&cadc=lf&caqid=7OEbWtnrHMSFZL-zk_AH"}
11-27 09:59:22.034 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/Ads: Server parameters: {"campaign_id":"739275108","gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544\/5224354917\/cak=no_cache&cadc=lf&caqid=7OEbWtnrHMSFZL-zk_AH"}
11-27 09:59:22.045 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
11-27 09:59:22.048 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-27 09:59:22.048 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
11-27 09:59:22.107 4990-4990/com.adget.adget V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {271c470c}
11-27 09:59:22.107 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
11-27 09:59:22.108 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-27 09:59:22.111 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
11-27 09:59:22.112 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
11-27 09:59:22.121 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
11-27 09:59:22.122 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=63 off=46092 len=2953
11-27 09:59:22.122 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:64 off:228796 len:643667
11-27 09:59:22.125 4990-5133/com.adget.adget W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
11-27 09:59:22.192 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fbdbb2fe520: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-27 09:59:22.194 4990-4990/com.adget.adget D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fbdbb2fe520: ver 2 0
11-27 09:59:22.218 4990-5139/com.adget.adget W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
11-27 09:59:22.219 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
11-27 09:59:22.228 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
11-27 09:59:22.231 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
11-27 09:59:22.237 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
11-27 09:59:22.237 4990-4990/com.adget.adget W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
11-27 09:59:22.901 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init 1.3.1
11-27 09:59:23.171 4990-5167/com.adget.adget I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
11-27 09:59:23.187 4990-5178/com.adget.adget I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
11-27 09:59:23.427 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
11-27 09:59:23.434 4990-4990/com.adget.adget I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

Comment: Can you post your complete error log?

Comment: print your stacktrace

Comment: You should take a look [the document](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) to know how to write and view logs with Logcat.

Comment: wait a second...

Comment: Change the Intent object name once

Comment: My friend you  have use firebase  on second or first Activity may be that cause problem.

Comment: toMoneyOut is second Activity and Intent object ,so it may problem change and run once @To.byTe.array

Comment: can you posgt the entire code of both your fist and second activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Switching from `TheScreen` to `moneyOut` you need to implement `OnClickListner`'s `onClick` method   in `TheScreen` Activity and On Button's `setOnClickListner` method pass `this` parameter.

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),moneyOut.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: i almost tried it before, it didn't help. And even Android developers site uses XML onClick

Comment: your log cat doesn't  show any specific error regarding intent or method. so when you run app clear logcat and give us the updated logcat . my suggestion is create new project first and try on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in a context for that activity but you are passing in a context from the OnClickListener class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, moneyOut.class);
startActivity(intent);
```